# How to get reference id if 2 column values match in excel vba

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Hi I'm new to Excel VBA and started working on creating a macro.  I have 2 sheets, Sheet1 has 4 columns (id, refid, value, code) and Sheet2 has 3 columns (refid, value, code).  I need to fill the Sheet1 refid column with Sheet2 refid column by comparing the value & code columns of Sheet1 and Sheet2. Is this possible using vlookup?  What are my options?

Comment: Share your vlookup formula you tried

Comment: i tried like this =vlookup(C2/D2,Sheet2!A1:C20,2/3,false)

Comment: That's not VBA, that's a formula. Edit your question and post your VBA code. IN YOUR QUESTION, not in a comment. By the way, why are you dividing C2 by D2 in the Vlookup? And what is the purpose of the division in the return column? Take a look at the Vlookup syntax. I'm not sure you've internalized it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `VLOOKUP`, the value you are looking for, has to be in the first column of the matrix you are searching in. So I would recommend the following. Add another column in Sheet2 as `Column A`. Fill it with the values of `value/code`. Your new formula should look like this.

```
=VLOOKUP(C2/D2,Sheet2!A$1:D$20,2,false)
```

Fill this in the column of `refid` in Sheet1. Column 2 in Sheet 2 should be the `refid`.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for the response.i could get the expected result when i concatenate 2 column values and use vlookup function.

Comment: You're welcome. Would you share your new formula with us?